# Projector dimension and count in Gram-Schmidt algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices, gram-schmidt

From what I have understood, when there is a vector $x \in C^m $, and we like to find the component of $x$ in direction of a particular vector such as $v$ , the projector is rank-one.
In Numerical Linear Algebra book by Trefethen and Bau,  it is written in the classical Gram-Schmidt For each value of $j$ , algorithm computes a single orthogonal projection of rank $m-(j-1)$.

$\underline{ Classical \quad Gram-Schmidt}\\\
\text{ for } j = 1 \text{ to } n\\\
    \quad\quad v_{j}=a_{j}\\\
    \quad\quad\text{for } i = 1 \text{ to } j-1\\\
    \quad\quad\quad \quad r_{ij} = q_{i}^{*}a_{j}\\\
    \quad\quad\quad \quad     v_{j} = v_{j} - r_{ij}q_{i}\\\
    \quad\quad  r_{jj} = ||v_{j}||_{2}\\\
    \quad\quad q_{j} = \frac { v_{j}} {r_{jj}}$

and in modified Gram-Schmidt there are $j-1$ projection of rank $m-1$.

$\underline{ Modified  \quad  Gram-Schmidt}\\\
\text{for } i = 1 \text{ to } n\\\
    \quad\quad v_{i}=a_{i}\\\
 \text{for } i = 1 \text{ to } n\\\
    \quad \quad r_{ii} = ||v_{i}||\\\
    \quad \quad q_{i} = \frac{v_{i}}  {r_{ii}}\\\
   \quad \quad\text{for } j = i+1 \text{ to } n\\\
   \quad \quad\quad \quad r_{ij} = q_{i}^{*}v_{j}\\\
    \quad \quad\quad\quad v_{j} = v_{j} - r_{ij}q_{i}\\\
   $

I traced the algorithm by hand but I cannot understand how it considered the rank and number of projections based on definition I mentioned earlier. For example in classical Gram-Schmidt if there is a matrix A ($m \times n$), when $j = 2$ there is one projection (projection of  $a_{2}$ into $q_{1}$),but from my understanding(based on book) there  should be two projections of rank m-1? how? does anyone know?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me point out that the difference in clasical and modified Gramm-Schmidt algorithms in finite dimension is *only* computational concern, i.e.,in finite arithmetic (i.e. actually implemented in computer), those algorithms are not equivalent. However for this question I believe that it does not matter, which one is considered. So, as you suggested, let us focus on the clasical Gramm-Schmidt.

Your understandingin the bottom paragraph seems valid to me. I only don't see the problem, since according to the algorithm , there is only one projector, i.e., matrix $q_1q_1^*$, which produces the vector $v_2$. Indeed, for $j=2$, the inner *for* loop will go *for $i=1$ to $2-1$ do*. Can you specify the struggle?

**Editted**
I believe that now I understand your struggle. The difference is in commutation. Explaining on an example, consider the three-dimensional case. If you want to project on the plane $\{(x,y,z)|z=0\}$, you either can project onto line $x$ and line $y$ and then add those projection up (corresponds to clasical Gramm-Schmidt) *or* you can project only with respect to $x$, orthogonalize with respect to $x$ (obtaining auxiliary vector $\tilde{v}$) and then project $\tilde{v}$ onto $y$ and orthogonalize (corresponds to modified Gramm-Schmidt).

Regarding the ranks, the confusion comes from the notation. What both of us considered as the projections was different operators from the ones in the book. Note that in book *$P_{q_2}$ projects onto the space orthogonal to $q_2$*. This projection has in only vector $q_2$ in its kernel and hence is of rank $m-1$. We however considered the projectors to project *onto the vector $q_2$*.

You can find these nuances on the wikipedia page mentioned above. I can also recommend a [learning video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/orthonormal-basis/v/linear-algebra-the-gram-schmidt-process) for you, which I found well done.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Specifically , when j=2, there is one projection to vector $q_{1}$. which I considered this as one projection of rank 1.how can I map this to 2 projection of rank m-1?

Comment: May this be a little misunderstanding? It seems as fi the authors refer to the *whole* algorithm as it is, i.e., not to *the $j$-th step* but rather *up to the $j$-th step*. Could it be? Otherwise, I do agree with your statement, for $j=2$ those algorithms indeed compute one rnak one orthogonal projection.

Comment: Nice ilustration is on [wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), where you can see that the projection will map onto zero the whole plane that is orthogonal to the vector $q_1$. Hence the kernel of that projection must be two dimensional, i.e., the rank is one

Comment: Thanks. I attached the page from the book. May be I understood this totally wrong.

Comment: I editted the answer according to the new question.

Comment: Thanks. It is kind of hard to imagine, but I think I understood to some extent.  The projection the book discussed is orthogonal to the projection  I discussed. The sum of rank of these two projections will add up to m.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.